# HERE Api "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined",

Tags: node.js, lambda

I have just created a geocoding lambda service using the
AWS Serverless Application Repository. This uses the HERE api.

When testing the api in API Gateway using the following url
https://geocode.json.search.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apikey=XXXXX&searchcode=glasgow
Which is generated by the lambda code generated by AWS

I see the error

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined",
        "    at getData (/var/task/geocode.js:38:36)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
    ]
}
```

I have probably made a simple error but can someone tell me how to resolve this. I cannot see in the Docs etc where the cause is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your lambda function where you have an undefined object :
You object is undefined before access to status attribut : yourObject.status